# import function from another file without running automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

To make simple I have two file, `a.py` and `b.py`

code inside `a.py`:

```py
from b import fun1

class sample:
    # sample Code related to kivy
```

code inside `b.py`:

```py
def fun1():
    # same code
def fun2():
    # same code
```

when I run file `a.py` immediately `b.py` run automatically
I search about this problem ,I know to solve this problem I have to use
if `__name__=="__main__"`:, but I don't understand how to use .

how I can call **fun1 or fun2**  inside `a.py` file

Comment: In your code `b.py` has two functions that are never called. What do you mean by "run automatically"? Nothing in the code you posted does anything.

Comment: You seem to ask two separate questions: one about how to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and one about how to run `fun1` and `fun2` inside another file. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, explanations about the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part are plenty on the internet, including on this site. What do you not understand about it that isn't yet explained?

Comment: I mean when run file a.py Because at beginning I write from b import fun1 ,python automatically run all code inside b.py file. but I don't want to run automatically. how I can avoid to run automatically

Comment: @Sam when importing it will only run code that is *not* in a function or `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. If you're writing a module don't have code sitting outside of a function.

Comment: @BTables thank you for your information

Comment: Running the code inside `b.py` is the one and only way that the functions defined in that code can come into existence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the functions inside of b.py without using the `if name=="main"`. You can solve this issue by putting the functions calls inside this if statement:

`b.py`

```py
def fun1():
    print("Hello")

def fun2():
    print("World")

if __name__ == "main":
    fun1()
```

That way, the function will only be called if you run `b.py` directly (that's what `__name__ = "main"` means)

For your other issue: to use the functions inside of `a.py` you have two main ways:

- you can import them directly (like you did) with either `from b import fun1, fun2` or `from b import *` (this will import all functions defined inside of `b.py`. By doing this you will be be able to use these functions directly by calling them like this:

`a.py`

```py
from b import fun1

fun1()
```

- or you can import `b.py` by using `import b`. Then you'd have to first name import and then the function when calling it:

```py
import b

b.fun2()
```

More on imports on the official Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Comment: Thank you for explain about __name__ = "main".